# How to assign an element a new namespace?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, namespaces

I am trying to assign a new namespace  to an element in the middle of an existing document using `createAttribute`. (Believe it or not, but that approach makes the most sense with my dataset.)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( '<doc xmlns="urn:x-one"><element><child1ofmany/></element></doc>' );
$xmlns = $doc->createAttribute( 'xmlns' );
$xmlns->value = 'urn:x-two';
$doc->getElementsByTagName( 'doc' )->item( 0 )->getElementsByTagName( 'element' ).appendChild( $xmlns );
echo $doc->saveXML();

/*
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <doc xmlns="urn:x-one">
        <element xmlns="urn:x-two">
            <child1ofmany/>
        </element>
    </doc>
*/
```

However this only works superficially. Using the `XSLTProcessor` or XPath on the document will show that `element` still belongs to the `urn:x-one` namespace.

The only work around I have found is stringifying `$doc` and reading the string as XML again.  Like this:

```
$doc->loadXML( $doc->saveXML() );
```

Surely there must be a better way to achieve this?

PS: `element` has tons of children so recreating it and its children (who should inherit `element`’s new namespace, by the by) would be a slow and painstaking process also.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your elements, call `createElementNS`.

Comment: The XML comes from external sources. They’re just missing a namespace change that the external source does not care about, but that I actually have to deal with.